# What iPhone apps are available for sending bulk SMSs?

Tags: iphone, sms

What iPhone apps can I use for sending bulk SMSs?

Hopefully something very simple to get started with....

Comment: How many bulk messages do you need to send? I normally just use the standard Messaging app.

Answer (score 1):

### Built-in Group Messaging

On any iPhone with iOS 4 you can enable group messaging which will allow you to message a group and for responses to be sent to the whole group:

1. Open Settings
2. Tap Messages.
3. Finally, flip the Group Messaging slider to On.

### Other soltions include:

- [Mass Text Message](http://www.masstextmessage.com/)
- [Beluga](http://belugapods.com)
- [textPlus](http://www.textplus.com/)

Comment: About the built-in method, I'm not seing it on my phone (I'm in France), I believe it's AT&T only.

Answer (score 0):

MassTextMsg app in the app store.   The only one I found that is simple, pulls your contacts from you address book, and doesn't force you to sign-up for an account or a different phone number.